# enable powershell tab-completion for invisible files and folders

Tags: powershell

I just noticed that the powershell tab-completion doesn't work for invisible files and folders.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not avilable in the Default PowerShell Host. But is avilable in [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org)...
 Sadly PowerGUI is more of a script editor than a Shell Console. But it does have the added benifite of a more advanced Visual Studio style IntelliSense.